How to get a NORTH NORTH WEST ARROW in Unicode?
Unicode has plenty of NORTH WEST ARROWs,
$ unicode north west arrow --max 0 |
grep --count 'NORTH \?WEST ARROW'
9

But no NORTH NORTH WEST ARROWs. How can I still possibly create one via some combining character or something?
I mean eight measly compass points?! Shall the mighty Unicode only emulate dime store compasses and that's it?

Use the US UTF8 locale character type: LC_ALL= LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 printf %b "\u2196" North West Arrows North North West?  What would that even look like?  Why?
